# php extract sub array with specific key

Tags: php

if i have the following array:

```
array(
   'var1' => 123,
   'var2' => 234,
   'var3' => 345
);
```

I would like to extract specific parts of this to build a new array i.e. var1 and var3.

The result i would be looking for is:

```
array(
   'var1' => 123,
   'var3' => 345
);
```

The example posted is very stripped down, in reality the array has a much larger number of keys and I am looking to extract a larger number of key and also some keys may or may not be present.

Is there a built in php function to do this?

Edit:

The keys to be extracted will be hardcoded as an array in the class i..e $this->keysToExtract

Comment: Under what condition are you extracting those keys?

Comment: I dont understand completely.  Can you explain what you mean by the criteria?

Comment: Well, what makes you choose `var1` and `var2` or is it random? Does it come from another array? Why are you choosing those 2 keys is my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = array_intersect_key($yourarray,array_flip(array('var1','var3')));
```

So, with your edit:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($yourarray,array_flip($this->keysToExtract));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a built in function to do this, try this :

```
$this->keysToExtract = array('var1', 'var3'); // The keys you wish to transfer to the new array

// For each record in your initial array
foreach ($firstArray as $key => $value)
{
    // If the key (ex : 'var1') is part of the desired keys
    if (in_array($key, $this->keysToExtract)
    {
        $finalArray[$key] = $value; // Add to the new array
    }
}

var_dump($finalArray);
```

Note that this is most likely the most efficient way to do this.